# How to know database type programmatically in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is there possible way to know which database server is use in JPA, programmatically? I think, there is a way, otherwise, JPA cannot transform `JPQL` to `native query` at runtime. My program also need to know `DB Server Type`. Is there any function for that feature?

I use `eclipseLink` & `jpa 2.0`

**My expected program is :**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA");
String dbPlatform = emf.getDBPlatform();
System.out.println(dbPlatform);
```

Output :

```
Oracle
MySql
MSSql
DB2
....
```

Comment: JPA can transform JPQL because you specify your database dialect in your used JPA implementation (e.g. in the `persistence.properties` in Hibernate). I don't think there is a way to reliably find out which type of database you are connected to.

Comment: Why do you need that information? If you describe your use-case getting that information won't be necessary. I suppose there's a way (eclipseLink has to talk to *some* JDBC driver and you could probably dig up where that link's stored and get it to tell you what type it is).

Comment: @mabi, I need to create a native query at runtime, if i don't know db type, how can I create native query.

Comment: @CycDemo: *Why* do you need to create a native query at runtime? If you describe the root problem you're trying to solve, people can help you solve that problem. (Possibly with a native query, possibly without.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I would like to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625953/jpql-create-table-at-runtime by using native query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never needed it, but I think the way to go is to get the [JDBC connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) and find in its properties that piece of information. In particular [getClientInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getClientInfo%28%29) and [getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) might be interesting.

This could be implementation specific, but as you said you use EclipseLink, you can use the following:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

[Reference from here.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager)

PS: I think you want to solve an intersting problem.

Comment: I have to do the same thing for a product which supports two different Databases. So while you are coding you don't know which one the code is going to query and when you need to do native SQL queries then this is the way to fire the right one depending on your db.

Comment: `connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()` returns the desired result, like "Oracle" or "H2" for example